# What is the file path when downloading a PDF using Struts 1.x?

Tags: java, struts-1

I have a little problem downloading a PDF file using Struts 1.x. I am not really sure of what is the file path when I'm actually going to download the file. So far I have this:

```
protected StreamInfo getStreamInfo(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

String fileDir="/descargasPDF"; //directory where all files are created and located 
String fileName="/tratado.pdf";   

String contentType = "application/pdf";

//File file = new File(NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE);
//I found this on the internet. 
//But it doesn't creates the file on the fileDir directory.
File file = new File(request.getRealPath("/WEB-INF")+fileDir+fileName);

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);


......

}
```

I'm not quite sure if I really want to save the pdf file temporary on my WEB-INF directory but I don't know how to this differently. Does anyone knows a better way to do this? if so, how can I do it?

Thank you.

EDIT

I forgot to specify that I'm generating the PDF and I'm using iText 5.3.

Comment: And what do you want to do with that PDF file afterwards?

Comment: Sorry. I am developing a web application that gives you the chance to download certain files. After the person clicks on Download, they can save it on their computers or go back to the app. So after the file is downloaded I don't really need it.

Comment: Which is exactly why I asked if you know any other ways to do this because I don't particularly like the idea of saving it on my WEB-INF directory and then delete it. :(

Comment: I take it this is a PDF you generate yourself, then?

Comment: Exactly. I'm using iText to generate de PDF.

Comment: Then you would be better off using a temporary directory, maybe even create it at the application start and removing it when the app stops. Store your PDF files in there.